# HTML css code copied from code pen giving

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgaRpz?editors=1000

I copied the HTML CSS code of this codepen 
but it is not giving same output .the division the gray background nothing is coming I am confused how 2 same code can give different output.

**MY HTML CODE:**

```
<html>

<style>
h1 {
  color: #DC2827;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-img {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.time {
  color: #DC2827;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li, p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs {
   text-align:center;
   float:none;
   display:inline-block;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}


</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well title text-center">
    <h1 class="heading">Ruby On Rails</h1>
    <h2>A  Web Aplication Framework</h2>
    <p>Ruby on Rails, or simply Rails, is a web application framework written in Ruby under MIT License. Rails is a model–view–controller (MVC) framework, providing default structures for a database, a web service, and web pages. It encourages and facilitates
  the use of web standards such as JSON or XML for data transfer, and HTML, CSS and JavaScript for display and user interfacing. In addition to MVC, Rails emphasizes the use of other well-known software engineering patterns and paradigms, including convention
  over configuration (CoC), don't repeat yourself (DRY), and the active record pattern.</p>
  </div>

   <div class="well">
    <img src="https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/750x422/531360_06c4.jpg" alt="Ruby on Rails Image" class="responsive main-img" />
  </div>


  <div class="well text-center">
    <h3>History</h3>
    <hr />

    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">July 2004 - </span>David Heinemeier Hansson first released Rails as open source.</li>

      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">February 2005 - </span>Commit rights to the project has been shared.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">August 2006 - </span>Apple announced that it would ship Ruby on Rails with Mac OS X v10.5 "Leopard".</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">March 2009 - </span>Rails version 2.3 was released.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">December 2008 - </span>Ruby on Rails announced it would work with the Merb project to bring "the best ideas of Merb" into Rails 3, ending the "unnecessary duplication" across both communities. Merb was merged with Rails as part
        of the Rails 3.0 release.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">August 2011 - </span>Rails 3.1 was released featuring Reversible Database Migrations, Asset Pipeline, Streaming, jQuery as default JavaScript library and newly introduced CoffeeScript and Sass into the stack.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">January 2012 - </span>Rails 3.2 was released with a faster development mode and routing engine (also known as Journey engine), Automatic Query Explain and Tagged Logging. Rails 3.2.x is the last version that supports Ruby 1.8.7.
        Rails 3.2.12 supports Ruby 2.0</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">June 2013 - </span>Rails 4.0 was released introducing Russian Doll Caching, Turbolinks, Live Streaming as well as making Active Resource, Active Record Observer and other components optional by splitting them as gems.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">April 2014 - </span>Rails 4.1 was released introducing Spring, Variants, Enums, Mailer previews, and secrets.yml.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">December 2014 - </span>Rails 4.2 was released introducing Active Job, asynchronous emails, Adequate Record, Web Console, and foreign keys.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">Early 2016 - </span>Rails 5.0 is set to release. Notable additions in Rails 5.0 include an option for an API-only application suitable for use as a backend to JavaScript or mobile applications. Also Action Cable for live features such as chat and notifications. </li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="well">
    <h3 class="text-center">Links</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="text-center">

      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#wiki" aria-controls="wiki" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Wiki</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#web" aria-controls="web" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Web</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#api" aria-controls="api" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">API</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#github" aria-controls="github" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Github</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="wiki"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails" target="_blank">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails</a></div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="web"><a href="http://rubyonrails.org/" target="_blank">http://rubyonrails.org/</a></div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="api"><a href="http://api.rubyonrails.org/" target="_blank">http://api.rubyonrails.org/</a></div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="github"><a href="https://github.com/rails/rails" target="_blank">https://github.com/rails/rails</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well text-center">
    <p> Copyrights &copy; none.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Please understand i have just started learning HTML and please any query if you have and want to ask to understand my question.See the code pen link and you will notice the differece between my code output and output on code pen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to inject bootstrap external library to your code.

add this link to your

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" 





href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and this  to your

```
    <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

with bootstrap:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/34298/

without bootstrap:

https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1437/

and add jquery as well

Comment: All you did was copy/paste Omer's answer - thats why I downvote.

Answer (score 0):

you need to inject bootstrap external library to your code.

add this link to your `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and this `<script>` to your `<body>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

with bootstrap:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/34298/

without bootstrap:

https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1437/

html:

```
   <html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well title text-center">
    <h1 class="heading">Ruby On Rails</h1>
    <h2>A  Web Aplication Framework</h2>
    <p>Ruby on Rails, or simply Rails, is a web application framework written in Ruby under MIT License. Rails is a model–view–controller (MVC) framework, providing default structures for a database, a web service, and web pages. It encourages and facilitates
  the use of web standards such as JSON or XML for data transfer, and HTML, CSS and JavaScript for display and user interfacing. In addition to MVC, Rails emphasizes the use of other well-known software engineering patterns and paradigms, including convention
  over configuration (CoC), don't repeat yourself (DRY), and the active record pattern.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="well">
    <img src="https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/750x422/531360_06c4.jpg" alt="Ruby on Rails Image" class="responsive main-img" />
  </div>


  <div class="well text-center">
    <h3>History</h3>
    <hr />

    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">July 2004 - </span>David Heinemeier Hansson first released Rails as open source.</li>

      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">February 2005 - </span>Commit rights to the project has been shared.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">August 2006 - </span>Apple announced that it would ship Ruby on Rails with Mac OS X v10.5 "Leopard".</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">March 2009 - </span>Rails version 2.3 was released.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">December 2008 - </span>Ruby on Rails announced it would work with the Merb project to bring "the best ideas of Merb" into Rails 3, ending the "unnecessary duplication" across both communities. Merb was merged with Rails as part
        of the Rails 3.0 release.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">August 2011 - </span>Rails 3.1 was released featuring Reversible Database Migrations, Asset Pipeline, Streaming, jQuery as default JavaScript library and newly introduced CoffeeScript and Sass into the stack.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">January 2012 - </span>Rails 3.2 was released with a faster development mode and routing engine (also known as Journey engine), Automatic Query Explain and Tagged Logging. Rails 3.2.x is the last version that supports Ruby 1.8.7.
        Rails 3.2.12 supports Ruby 2.0</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">June 2013 - </span>Rails 4.0 was released introducing Russian Doll Caching, Turbolinks, Live Streaming as well as making Active Resource, Active Record Observer and other components optional by splitting them as gems.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">April 2014 - </span>Rails 4.1 was released introducing Spring, Variants, Enums, Mailer previews, and secrets.yml.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">December 2014 - </span>Rails 4.2 was released introducing Active Job, asynchronous emails, Adequate Record, Web Console, and foreign keys.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="time">Early 2016 - </span>Rails 5.0 is set to release. Notable additions in Rails 5.0 include an option for an API-only application suitable for use as a backend to JavaScript or mobile applications. Also Action Cable for live features such as chat and notifications. </li>
    </ul>


  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <h3 class="text-center">Links</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="text-center">

      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#wiki" aria-controls="wiki" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Wiki</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#web" aria-controls="web" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Web</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#api" aria-controls="api" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">API</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#github" aria-controls="github" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Github</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="wiki"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails" target="_blank">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails</a></div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="web"><a href="http://rubyonrails.org/" target="_blank">http://rubyonrails.org/</a></div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="api"><a href="http://api.rubyonrails.org/" target="_blank">http://api.rubyonrails.org/</a></div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="github"><a href="https://github.com/rails/rails" target="_blank">https://github.com/rails/rails</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well text-center">
    <p> Copyrights &copy; none.</p>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
h1 {
  color: #DC2827;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-img {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.time {
  color: #DC2827;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li, p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs {
   text-align:center;
   float:none;
   display:inline-block;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: but sir in that pen he has not added any bootstrap still it works how?

Comment: in your codepen click on settings and then click on css tab you will see the bootstrap added under the Add External CSS

Comment: Thnak you it did the trick however one problem persists in the end u see there are 4 floating buttons when i click on other buttons text doesnt change

Comment: you only need to add jquery script to your body and this will solve the problem, <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> but this script must be before the javascript script

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to include css and js from the code pen.[image]

Comment: there is no jss and i am saying that when i copy these codes of html css to my local notepad and run it on browser it gives diff output